# Having troubles implementing Dijkstra algorithm in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, list, dictionary, ocaml, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in OCaml, this is the pseudo-code I'm following :

[image]

So far, I've written those functions, putting everything in it would be too long and maybe not necessary at this point. But I'll give their type.

```
(* init_dist build the distances (distance Map) between the nodes given a nodes list. *)
let init_dist nodes source
val init_dist : node list -> node -> float DistMap.t = <fun>

(* min_elt_and_key return a (node,float) tuple, by finding the minimum key and returning its key with it. *)
let min_elt_and_key map ~compare_element
val min_elt_and_key : 'a DistMap.t -> compare_element:('a -> 'a -> int) -> node * 'a = <fun>

(* update_distances updates dMap and prevMap based on n1 and n2, returns a tuple of Map *) 
let update_distances n1 n2 dMap prevMap

(* find_minimum returns the minimum node based on the distance map. *)
let find_minimum nodes_Q first_node map
val find_minimum : node list -> node -> float DistMap.t -> node = <fun>
```

And here's where I am at.

```
let dijkstra graph source target =
  let nodes = Graph.nodes in
  let distanceMap = init_dist nodes source in
  let prevMap = DistMap.empty in
  let nodes_Q = Graph.nodes in
  let rec dijkstra_aux dMap pMap nodes_Q target =
```

(`Graph.nodes` has type `node list`)

My trouble here is that I don't know how I would be able to look for the minimum by going through nodes_Q, remove it, and keep going. Loops have `unit` type in OCaml so doing imperative programming here would be quit hard, plus the end goal is to return a tuple of map (dist and prev). Plus another problem would be raised, how could I code something for the `for` loop in the `while` ? I basically wrote every function necessary to write the algorithm, but assembling them isn't an easy task.

I've seen this link : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#OCaml

However, I've only started coding in OCaml a few months back and my data structures seems fairly different than the ones I have.

What would you recommend me to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode Dijkstra's algorithm [Ocaml](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#OCaml)

Comment: Thanks. However, not gonna lie, I've seen this link, but I just started OCaml a few months back and my data structures seems fairly different than the ones in the example.

Comment: That's why it is given as a comment and not an answer. It doesn't help you learn, it just gives the answer. Nice that you explain why, you should note the link and why you don't want it as part of an answer in the question as many people don't read comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to think about an imperative loop in a functional language is to re-imagine the body of the loop as a function. Any values manipulated in the loop are parameters of the function. To do the next iteration of the loop, the function calls itself recursively with new values of the parameters.

The values manipulated in your case are Q, dist, and prev. So you can imagine the final loop in your pseudo-code as something like this:

```
let rec dijkstra_aux q dist prev =
    if empty q then
        (dist, prev)
    else
        let min_elt = smallest_element_of q in
        let q' = remove_element q min_elt in
        let (dist', prev') = update_neighbors q dist prev in
        dijkstra_aux q' dist' prev'
```